# GDAL og2ogr: insert/update existing PostGIS table from shapefile

Tags: postgis, gdal, sql, ogr2ogr, append

I work with Windows, PostGIS and GDAL (I use gdal/ogr2ogr from the command prompt. Version of GDAL available under C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\bin).

Up to now, within my PostGIS database, I was inserting new features into an existing table using SQL queries :

```
INSERT INTO SCHEMA_human.TableDestination (
"fieldXX",
"geom")

SELECT
"fieldXX",
"geom"

FROM source_table
```

Or features updates  using

```
update
set
from
where
```

It worked. But the limit of this approach is that it requires first importing the shp into the PostGIS database beforehand. So my goal is to directly insert new features/ update (from shp source file / toward PostGIS destination table using GDAL. In order to avoid/skip/break free this import of shp in the bdd beforehands.

The Source file is 1 POINT shapefile (EPSG 2154).
The target/destination table is therefore an existing PostGIS table of POINTS (EPSG 2154)
(The schema of the destination table is NOT the default public schema but the 'human' schema.)

There seem to be two approaches to accomplish this task. Either use the -append options associated with -fieldmap. (or - update for updates). Or the approach with -sql by defining the SQL query.
I priorize the approach with -sql if possible.

Here is the structure I was thinking of for example for an insert.

```
ogr2ogr - progress - append D:\XXX.shp
-f PG:"dbname='dbname' host='ipXXXXX' port='5432' user='XXXX' password='XXXX' active_schema='human'"
-sql
INSERT INTO human_schema.TableName (
"field1",
"field2",
"field3",
"geom")

--selection of SHP fields
SELECT
"field1",
"field2",
"field3",
"geom"

FROM
shp
```

Am I wrong?

Where are my mistakes?

With this method, is it possible to specify the fields of the source shp within the SQL clause? (non-geom field and geom field?).

When, like me, we have a shp input and a PostGIS table output, should we rather prioritize the approach with -append -addfield (or -update) rather than the approach with -sql?

For input shp, the name of geometry field  (that shoud be set into sql query) is always "geom"?

If not, what would be the way to find out?

Comment: INSERT and UPDATE are very different tasks. We use a Focused question/Best answer model,  and packing both of these in a single Question runs up against the One question per Question policy. Two other thoughts: 1) Shapefile is a *awful* format for transfer of database information -- the lack of complete range of data types and failure to support NULL values can be a serious issue 2) I have often used a staging table model because the long pole in the  performance tent is the upload to the database; both INSERT and UPDATE are much faster from tables than external sources.

Answer (score 3):

If the field names in PostGIS and shapefile are the same a command like this should work.

```
ogr2ogr - progress - append 
-f PG:"dbname='dbname' host='ipXXXXX' port='5432' user='XXXX' password='XXXX' active_schema='human'" D:\XXX.shp
-sql
"select
field1,
field,
field3 from XXX"
```

If names are different try `select field1 AS another_name`. Geometry column is selected automatically if the source data comes from shapefile with the default SQL dialect.

The `-sql` parameter in ogr2ogr supports only for selecting a dataset. The driver knows how to use INSERT INTO etc.

Some other SQL commands can be executed with `ogrinfo`, including updates if they can be expressed as a single command `ogrinfo -sql UPDATE XXX set foo='bar' where foo='foo'...`, but updating a set of rows is not supported at the moment. There is a new pull request https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/5849 that may add a possibility to UPSERT into ogr2ogr.